# distinguish pages into a pdf stream via regular expression

Tags: regex, pdf

i need to extract some information from a pdf stream. 
It's quite simple to extract the relevant text, since it is something like:

```
BT /Fo0 7.20 Tf 67.81 569.38 Td 0.000 Tc (TOTAL AMOUNT) Tj ET
```

I can consider fixed the y position, while the x position is variable due to giustification.
But my problem is recognize the beginning of a page and its end.

Comment: Which is the relevant text part?

Comment: In this example, "TOTAL AMOUNT". But in some pages it is missing, and i need not just to extract it when it is present, but list the pages in which it is not present, as well.

Comment: It would help if you posted a (link to a) sample PDF that is *really* representative for your stuff. Do these PDFs have multiple pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be sure that all the PDFs you encounter with your 'information extractor' are behaving so nicely. Or can you be, because you *know* they are?

Otherwise, it can very well happen that the PDF code which you encounter looks like:

```
BT 
  /Fo0 7.20 Tf 
  67.81 569.38 Td 
  0.000 Tc 
  (TO)12(T)13(AL A)11(M)14(OUNT) TJ 
ET
```

That is, ...

- ...using `TJ` instead of `Tj`, to allow individal glyph positioning,
- ...having more linebreaks,
- ...and maybe many more modifikations.

In order to reliably get to the page's text content, you have to parse the structure of the PDF, in short:

1. find all objects of `/Type /Page`;
2. go to each of these page objects and retrieve the info about which its respective `/Contents` is;

   - the `/Contents` may point to single stream, or
   - the `/Contents` may point to an array of streams;
3. go to this content object and extract its stream(s).

In practical terms, the first of the above steps can turn out a bit more complicated:

- find and go to the `trailer <<...>>` section
- in the trailer locate the info about the document's `/Root` object
- go to the root object
- extract the info about the `/Pages` from the `/Root` object
- go to the `/Pages` object (which is an intermedia *page tree node* with kids and parent;
- find all descendands of this page tree node from inspecting the `/Kids` object
- go to each respective object listed by `/Kids`;

  - it could be of `/Type /Pages` (in which case it is another page tree *node*, not a tree *leaf*, and you have to follow down the tree further on);
  - it could be of `/Type Page` (in which case you arrived a a page tree *leaf* which means you *really* arrived at a page).

At this point I should note, that the first page you found following this journey is page 1. The next is page 2, etc. Note, that no page has any metadata saying "I'm page number N" -- it's all depending on the order you parse the page tree staring from the root object.

Now that you really found content streams, you are facing two more problems:

1. The content streams you are looking for may not be in clear text at all (like your code showed). Content streams are very frequently compressed by one of the allowed compression schemes, and you'll have to expand them before you can parse for text content.

   To see if a stream is compressed, watch out for the respective **Decode* keyword (very frequently appearing as  `/Filter /FlateDecode`).
2. Once you successfully uncompressed the page's content stream, you may encounter totally un-intuitive character codes describing your text. It may not at all be the same type of well behaving ASCII as you imagine and showed in your example code.

   You'll have to look up fonts (even multi-byte fonts like CID), their encodings, CMaps and what-not.

   Unless, as I questioned in my initial sentence, you *know* that's not happening in your specific use case...

Comment: Great answer, it gives a good overall of how a pdf file is structured. I'm not trying to interpreter a pdf in a reliable way. The purpose is realizing a human assisted data-extractor, more like an OCR. The documents are "forms" (not pdf-forms!) with a box-constrainted layout. So ideally, i can say that there is a box with (x0;y0-x1;y1) on every page (the total amout of the example). I need to extract the text in this area. Clearly i cannot rely on text starting x,y, but need something more sophisticated, togheter with all the considerations you made. For uncompressing the stream i used iText.